# Adding multiple tasks to interface. Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am sure this is a very nooby question but i can not find it anywhere on the internet, or maybe am looking wrong but.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>  
{    
//how do i fit this code--> idUIAccelerometerDelegate
//into the interface where it is the only place it can work?
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    UIImage *image;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker2;
  //the code above is already linked with the @interface at the top thingy.


 //but now i also want to link the @accelerometer but it won't let me without any errors.
    float valueX;
    float valueY;

}
@property (nanotomic,strong)  IBOutlet UIButton *snow;

-(void)awakeAccelerometer;
-(void)acc

- (IBAction)takePhoto;
- (IBAction)chooseExisting;

@end
```

thank you for any help sorry if i wasted your time. down vote me by all means if you wish to.

Comment: May I suggest that you reformat your question/code slightly? I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: so i want to add the accelerometer reference but also the image reference in the interface at the top but it won't let me. either only 1 or the other. so how do i ad both of them without getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are wanting your object to receive the messages from the accelerometer, If that is true then you dont want to add a delegate, you want to become the delegate.

your class will Conform the the UIAccelerometerDelegate much like it does the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and the UINavigationControllerDelegate and will look something like this

```
// Your new interface line.
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

and you would add the following function to your class

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{
    // Handle the accelorometer and acceleration objects to determine what happened.
}
```

Be aware that this method is deprecated in ios 5, and now you should look into Core Motion. This should work on ios 6 still, but its a good possibility it will go away in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand the question - if so, the answer is that this line

```
id <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
```

is incomplete (declaring a variable without naming it, and no terminating `;`). Try

```
 id <UIAccelerometerDelegate> delegate;
```

you can put this on any line between the `{` and `}` where all of your other instance variable declarations are in the @interface. For example, exactly where your  first `//comment` is now.

also you have a typo lower down

`nanotomic` should be `nonatomic`

**update**
although I think I answered your question as you required, you should ignore my advice and follow @Volure DarkAngel's answer. I was focussing on the syntax, not on the task you were trying to achieve.

Comment: Well that _was_ the answer until Atif edited the question! But it's probably what you are after anyway...